# Android grid view on click listener get selected item

Tags: java, android, gridview, onclicklistener

I am trying to get the selected item from grid view in Android development. Here is the list of drawable I used to populate the grid view:

```
private static Integer[] iconlist = {
        R.drawable.food_icon, R.drawable.transport_icon, R.drawable.entertainment_icon,
        R.drawable.bill_icon, R.drawable.others_icon, R.drawable.salary_icon,
        R.drawable.investment_icon, R.drawable.bonus_icon, R.drawable.medication_icon,
        R.drawable.drinks_icon, R.drawable.car_icon, R.drawable.mask_icon,
        R.drawable.shopping_icon, R.drawable.lottery_icon, R.drawable.pet_icon,
        R.drawable.movie_icon, R.drawable.plant_icon, R.drawable.paint_icon,
};
```

And gridview on click listener:

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View v, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Grid Item " + (position + 1) + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int selected = position + 1;
            for(int i = 0; i < iconlist.length; i++){
                if(iconlist[i] == selected){

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I managed to get the correct integer position based on the clicks. What I am trying to do is based on the selected drawable, I am trying to extract out the string.

For example, when transport icon is clicked, I am trying to get the "transport_icon" string from "R.drawable.transport_icon" and store it as string. However, I not sure how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: do u want to store this ""R.drawable.transport_icon"" as string?

Comment: No no, I am trying to store the "transport_icon" as string only.

Comment: First remove position+1 for get selected items.Because iconList also start from 0 position.

Comment: I tried to do this: String iconStr = String.valueOf(iconlist[position + 1]);
                System.out.println(iconStr); But end up I am getting some random string like 2130837609

Comment: Why you compare selected == iconList[i],iconlist contains id's (like this 0x7f010022) and selected is int type.

Comment: I realized it was a mistake, I removed the for loop and replaced with the two lines above but still no luck

Comment: and can u say why?

Comment: @EliasFazel As in I can simply get the selected item by (iconlist[position]) so the for loop is not necessary. Other than that, I have no idea how to extract out the string.

Comment: What do you want after getting right items from position.

Comment: @niveshshashtri For example I selected on transport icon, its drawable is R.drawable.transport_icon, I am trying to extract out "transport_icon" string only.

Comment: For this you simply define one more string list with icon list in adapter.So you will get name directly via position like key's of id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first define a drawable from integer array (the ids)

```
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(iconlist[n]);
```

and you can get name of resources like this

```
String name = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(ID);
```

this method should return what you need.

Comment: getDrawable requires API 21 but my current one minimum is 16. Any alternatives? Also, how do I parse the drawable into int to extract out the string?

Comment: add getResources()

Comment: String name = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(ID); this one i wrote in answer test and u will get the name of drawable >>> text after R.drawable.TEXT

Answer (score -1):

You can try in below way:

```
Context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.transport_icon)
```

or

```
Context.getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.transport_icon)
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName(int)